two functions "greet_user" and "display_message_random" aren't getting called separetly
I'm a python beginner and i'm trying to make a simple app where a simple GUI window pops up and the program asks the user to enter their name and after clicking the "Greet me!" button the program is supposed to display a greeting and then display a motivation message after a random time interval which in this case is 1 to 2 minutes.
First part works great, the GUI window pops up, i can enter the name and press the button but then nothing happens - however if i wait 1 to 2 minutes, the greeting finally gets displayed ALONG with the motivational message. Instead I want it to first display the greeting and then after 1 to 2 minutes to display the random motivational message. I'm using pycharm as my IDE. Here's the complete code:
import time
import random
import tkinter

messages = [
    "You're doing great. Keep it up!",
    "Let's keep working. No time to waste!",
    "Don't stop now! There's still work to do.",
    "Keep up the good work! You're killing it!",
    "Don't get distracted. Stay focused!"
]

def display_message_random(label):
    while True:
        delay_in_minutes = random.randint(1, 2)
        delay_in_seconds = delay_in_minutes * 60
        time.sleep(delay_in_seconds)
        selected_message = random.choice(messages)
        label.config(text=selected_message)
        root.update()

# Creates the main pop up window
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Albi - Your Productivity Pal!")

# Get user name (in the GUI)
user_name_label = tkinter.Label(root, text="Hi! Hope you're doing well. I'm Albi. What's your name?\n")
user_name_label.pack()

user_name_entry = tkinter.Entry(root)
user_name_entry.pack()

def greet_user():
    user_name = user_name_entry.get()
    greeting_label = tkinter.Label(root, text="Nice to meet you " + user_name + "!\n" + "I hope you have a productive session!")
    greeting_label.pack()
    user_name_label.destroy()  # Remove the user name prompt after greeting
    user_name_entry.destroy()  # Remove the entry field after greeting
    display_message_random(label)  # Start displaying messages

greet_button = tkinter.Button(root, text="Greet Me!", command=greet_user)
greet_button.pack()

# Label to display messages
label = tkinter.Label(root, text="", font=("Arial", 14))
label.pack()

# Start the main event loop - calls the function
root.mainloop() 

I tried putting the putting the 2nd function before the function and somehow I managed to get the greeting to show up but then the random messages would never get displayed.
I'm very new to Python so please explain to me what the issue is like I'm 5. I'd really appreciate any help. Thank you!

Avoid while loop  and calling time.sleep() in the main thread of a tkinter GUI application as it will block tkinter mainloop() from handling pending events and updates.  For your case, you need to update the label before calling time.sleep().

Doesn't look like you're using the time library, so you can probably delete that without issue.
First, you should define Label earlier in your code because you need it for the greet_user() function and you use greet_user() in your greet_button code. So you need Label defined before this.
Second, you should reconfigure your wait system so your while loop has a way to end. You can use the .after() method for that.
try this
import random
import tkinter

messages = [
    "You're doing great. Keep it up!",
    "Let's keep working. No time to waste!",
    "Don't stop now! There's still work to do.",
    "Keep up the good work! You're killing it!",
    "Don't get distracted. Stay focused!"
]

def display_message_random(label:tkinter.Label):
    delay_in_minutes = random.randint(1, 2)
    delay_in_seconds = delay_in_minutes * 60
    selected_message = random.choice(messages)
    label.config(text=selected_message)
    root.update()
    root.after(delay_in_seconds * 1000, display_message_random, label)

# Creates the main pop up window
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Albi - Your Productivity Pal!")

# Label to display messages
label = tkinter.Label(root, text="", font=("Arial", 14))
label.pack()

# Get user name (in the GUI)
user_name_label = tkinter.Label(root, text="Hi! Hope you're doing well. I'm Albi. What's your name?\n")
user_name_label.pack()

user_name_entry = tkinter.Entry(root)
user_name_entry.pack()

def greet_user():
    user_name = user_name_entry.get()
    greeting_label = tkinter.Label(root, text="Nice to meet you " + user_name + "!\n" + "I hope you have a productive session!")
    greeting_label.pack()
    user_name_label.destroy()  # Remove the user name prompt after greeting
    user_name_entry.destroy()  # Remove the entry field after greeting
    display_message_random(label)  # Start displaying messages

greet_button = tkinter.Button(root, text="Greet Me!", command=greet_user)
greet_button.pack()

# Start the main event loop
root.mainloop()


If the OP is not using the time library, why is delay_in_minutes = random.randint(1, 2), delay_in_seconds = delay_in_minutes * 60, and time.sleep(delay_in_seconds) being used? Sure, it's not necessary, but you can't just say they didn't use it.

It is not necessary to call root.update() inside display_message_random().
